# How to transform a set of qualitative data into numbers according to quantity?

Tags: python, r

i have a data frame like this:

```
country level_of_smoking clasification_country
germany  high              A
greece   low               B
USA      medium            A
france   none              A
italy    low               B
spain    medium            A
```

and so on (the list is longer than this is just a example)

so, I wonder how transform this dataframe into something like this:

```
       high   medium    low    none
classA 1        2        0      1
classB 0        0        2      0
```

please if you can help me with R or python code that make this.

Comment: Try `table(df1[-1])`

Comment: In `tidyverse`, `df1 %>%
  count(class, smoking) %>%
  spread(smoking, n, fill = 0)`

Answer (score 0):

### Python

- Use `.groupby` and `.unstack`
- [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

#### Data:

```py
country smoking class
 greece     low     B
    USA  medium     A
 france    none     A
  italy     low     B
  spain  medium     A
```

```py
import pandas as pd

# to read test data from clipboard
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+')
df.groupby(['class', 'smoking'])['smoking'].count().unstack()
```

#### Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `R`, this can be done with `table` (No packages used)

```
table(df1[3:2])
#   smoking
#class low medium none
#    A   0      2    1
#    B   2      0    0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(country = c("greece", "USA", "france", "italy", 
"spain"), smoking = c("low", "medium", "none", "low", "medium"
), class = c("B", "A", "A", "B", "A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a long to wide problem, you can also use `reshape2::dcast()`

```r
data <- structure(list(country = c("greece", "USA", "france", "italy", 
"spain"), value = c("low", "medium", "none", "low", "medium"), 
    class = c("B", "A", "A", "B", "A")), class = c("data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))


reshape2::dcast(
    data,
    class ~ value, # formula
    value.var = "country", 
    fun.aggregate = length # use length as aggregation function
    )
```

```r
  class low medium none
1     A   0      2    1
2     B   2      0    0
```